# How to return many Child Collections Count() in a single entity framework query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have two entities, Parent and Child, in Entity Framework.

The parent has a collection of Child entities.

In my query, I want to return only the Parent entities (the fully typed EF types) and also the Count() of the Child entities (this could be set to a property on the Parent), but I only want to do this in one call to the database, without writing a custom S-Proc. Is this possible?

Essential, I want to turn this into a single query:

```
EFContext content = new EFContext();
IQueryable<Parent> parentQuery = context.Parent.Select();
foreach(Parent parent in parentQuery)
{
  parent.NoChildItems = parent.Childs.Count();
}
```

When I activate the enumerator on this this, it calls the database for the list, and again for each Count() query. I return approx 100 items each time and so would rather not make 100 seperate calls just for the number of child items.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
IQueryable parentQuery = context.Parent.Select(p => new { Parent = p, ChildCount = p.Childs.Count() });
```

**EDIT**

If you define:

```
public class ParentModel
{
    public Task Parent { get; set; }
    public int ChildCount { get; set; }
}
```

you can use

```
IQueryable parentQuery = context.Parent.Select(p => new ParentModel { Parent = p, ChildCount = p.Childs.Count() });
```

**EDIT**

You can also do:

```
var parentQuery = context.Parent.Select(p => new { Parent = p, ChildCount = p.Childs.Count() }).ToList();
parentQuery.ForEach(p => p.Parent.ChildCount = p.ChildCount);
var result = return parentQuery.Select(p => p.Parent);
```

Short and you have your property populated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however is there a way to do it without using an anonymous class?

Comment: Thought you were going to say that!
Nevermind, thanks for your help.

Comment: The above solution but results in multiple db calls. How can the count be retrieved in one call for all records in ParentModel?

Comment: @RobinKedia This may not result in multiple DB calls in EF6.